# Getting stuck trying to prove limits in terms of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm struggling to prove that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(-1,8)} xy = -8$$

I know that

$$\mid f(x,y) - 8 \mid \ = \ \mid xy - 8\mid \ = \  \mid(x+1)(y-8)+ 8x - y + 16 \mid$$

By the triangle inequality, this is less or equal than

$$\mid (x+1)(y-8)\mid + \mid8x - y + 16 \mid \ = \ \mid x+1 \mid \ \mid y-8 \mid \ + \ \mid 8(x+1) + (-1)(y - 8) \mid$$

The second term of the sum is the easy part. Applying triangle inequality again we can say it's less than 9$\delta$. But the first term of the sum would only be less than $\delta^{2}$. And I can't express every $\epsilon > 0$ in terms of $\delta^{2} + 9\delta$, can I?

Comment: Craeful! By the triangle inequality, your first expression is **less than** the second.

Answer (score 2):

If $\delta <\sqrt {\epsilon /2}$ and $\delta < \frac {\epsilon} {18}$ then $\delta^{2}+9\delta <\epsilon /2 +\epsilon /2 <\epsilon$. So take $\delta$ less then the minimum of $\sqrt {\epsilon /2}$ and $\frac {\epsilon} {18}$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with $|xy - (-8)| = |xy \color{red}{+}8|$.

Then it is straight forward:

$$|xy - (-8)| = |xy - (-1)y + (-1)y - (-1\cdot 8)|$$ $$ \leq |x -(-1)||y| +|-1||y-8|=|x+1||y| + |y-8|$$
Now, for $1 > \delta >0$ you get

$$|y||x+1| + |y-8| \stackrel{|y-8|<1\Rightarrow |y| <9}{\leq} 9\delta +\delta = 10\delta$$

Hence, for $\epsilon > 0$ you may choose $\delta_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{10}\min(1,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Why did you express $\delta_{\epsilon}$ as $\frac{1}{10} min(1,\epsilon)$ and not as $min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{10})$?

Comment: @ydnfmew : Because. you get at the end of the estimation $|xy - (-8)| < \color{blue}{10}\delta$. If you play it through with, for example, $\epsilon_0 = 1$, you obtain for $\delta_{\epsilon_0} = 1$ an upper bound of $|xy - (-8)| < 10\delta_{\epsilon_0} = 10$. But you need $|xy - (-8)| <\epsilon_0 = 1$.